# Unable to connect to my Posgres server using JDBC driver and sql2o

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to setup a simple java todo-list application to access a postgres database using the `jdbc postgres driver`, `sql2o` and `spark-mvc`.

This is my sql2o command for setting up a connection to the database:

```
static Sql2o sql2o = new Sql2o("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/todo-development", "jake", "password");
```

These are the versions I am using:

```
compile group: 'org.sql2o', name: 'sql2o', version: '1.5.4'
```

compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: "9.4-1201-jdbc41"

When I run my application I am getting this stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sql2o.Sql2oException: Could not acquire a connection from DataSource - FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
    at org.sql2o.Connection.createConnection(Connection.java:291)
    at org.sql2o.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:51)
    at org.sql2o.Sql2o.open(Sql2o.java:225)
    at Todo.save(Todo.java:30)
    at Todo.<init>(Todo.java:19)
    at App.main(App.java:14)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:684)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:199)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:127)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:41)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:414)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:282)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.sql2o.GenericDatasource.getConnection(GenericDatasource.java:62)
    at org.sql2o.Connection.createConnection(Connection.java:288)
    ... 5 more
```

Any idea as to what could be causing this?

Comment: What's the PostgreSQL version?

Comment: It is whatever the latest PG version on Homebrew is. I believe 9.4.2, I will double check when I get back into the office tomorrow.

Comment: Weird. Works for me (9.4.2, Fedora 21).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by restarting my computer. Sometimes it's the simple things.